# Bluesnap Apple Pay Wallet Error on sandbox

Tags: applepay, bluesnap

I'm working with the Bluesnap Apple Pay integration and have not been able to complete a transaction through the sandbox for over two weeks. The behaviour does not exist in production.

At first, I was getting this response:

```
{
   "errorName": "WALLET_PROCESSING_FAILURE",
   "code": "23003",
   "description": "Wallet processor is currently unavailable, please try again later"
}
```

After reporting to Bluesnap, they contacted Apple and that error code was replaced by:

```
{
   "errorName": "INVALID_WALLET_PAYMENT_DATA",
   "code": "23010",
   "description": "Error getting wallet Transaction Details"
}
```

I've tried multiple cards, and the only one that does not give this error is one of the test Visa cards, which just stays on the Apple Pay modal and stays in a loop where you validate, it says "Payment Not Completed". and then you validate again, etc etc etc.

Has anyone else been experiencing this behaviour?

Comment: This is probably not on-topic for SO since it doesn't seem to have anything to do with a question about your code, but rather a question that should be directed at a third-party. Even if someone saw the same thing, the question and any solution would probably not age well, making this a poor candidate for future Q&A.

Comment: You are probably right. I've directed questions at said third-party and they just say that Apple is to blame and that they are "investigating" I'm mostly just hoping to determine if it's only affecting Bluesnap Apple Pay transactions, or maybe just my merchant's transactions. I'm just totally at a loss for what to do and I need to test my code before it can be released. =(

Comment: Yes, that does sound like a challenge. You'd think third parties so invested in a flagship API would support it better, or at least be more clear about the implications of the problem so you can set your expectations. Maybe there is an online forum somewhere where you can coordinate with other consumers of the API? SO is just not a great place for this sort of transient info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that Bluesnap has a limitation where, if you want to use Apple Pay for native mobile apps, that sandbox will no longer support web payments through Apple Pay. We added a separate sandbox for our mobile team and Apple Pay works for web transactions again. Something to do with how they encrypt/decrypt their wallet tokens.

Answer (score 0):

What iOS are you running? And are you logged into the apple pay sandbox icloud account ? I would suggest contacting bluesnap support with this specific issue.

Comment: I'm running High Sierra on a touchid MacBook and I'm logged into my sandbox account. I contacted Bluesnap and they said it was an Apple problem and that Apple had said that their sandbox is "generally unstable" and to try again later. I've been trying twice a day for two weeks and am still having no luck.

Is this just me? Are you able to process transactions through the Apple Pay sandbox? Could it be isolated to Bluesnap Apple Pay transactions?